# Ajax stuck when try call second time

Tags: ajax, json

My Ajax code doesn't want to answer again when ajax code run one time.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type    :   "POST",
    url     :   "scriptNext.php",
    dataType:   'json',
    data    :   {aId: actId},   
    success :   function(retour){

        $("#actionAll").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#actionAll").html(retour.message1);
            $("#actionAll").fadeIn();
        });


        $("#btnNext").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#btnNext").html(retour.message2);
            $("#btnNext").fadeIn();
        });


    },
    error:  function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
        alert("Erreur appel page jQuery !");
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Code to call Ajax function:

```
<DIV ID=actionAll CLASS=result>
    butter
</DIV>

<DIV CLASS=item ID=btnNext>
  <A HREF=# class=PlusUn actionId=1 attribuid=actionAll >Next
</DIV>
```

the called function (scriptNext.php) return well data (sugar) first time, but, after update HREF item  field, can't be called for second time - nothing happening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I would take,

a. Check if the ajax call is in progress and abort it before calling the same method again.

b. In order to do that, follow the code structure I've provided below,

```
 var getDataAjaxCall;//declare this variable

function GetData(){

//check if previous call is still pending and abort it before making a new 
//one.
if (getDataAjaxCall&& getDataAjaxCall.readyState != 4)
        getDataAjaxCall.abort();

getDataAjaxCall = $.ajax({
                type    :   "POST",
                url     :   "scriptNext.php",
                dataType:   'json',
                data    :   {aId: actId},   
                success :   function(retour){

                    $("#actionAll").fadeOut(function() {
                        $("#actionAll").html(retour.message1);
                        $("#actionAll").fadeIn();
                    });

                    $("#btnNext").fadeOut(function() {
                        $("#btnNext").html(retour.message2);
                        $("#btnNext").fadeIn();
                    });
                },
                error:  function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                if (ajaxOptions!= 'abort') {                
                    alert("Erreur appel page jQuery !");
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
                }
             }
       }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be elegent and against the principle of ajax, but try to add :

```
async: false
```

worked for me but still can't figure why.